# Hilbert style proof of $\text{A}\vdash \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B}$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

Could somebody give a hint how to prove the following theorem $\text{A}\vdash \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B}$ using a Hilbert style proof?
Three axiom schemas

(A1) $\alpha \to \left( \beta \to \alpha  \right)$

(A2) $\left( \alpha \to \left( \beta \to \gamma  \right) \right)\to \left( \left( \alpha \to \beta  \right)\to \left( \alpha \to \gamma  \right) \right)$

(A3) $\left( \neg \alpha \to \neg \beta  \right)\to \left( \beta \to \alpha  \right)$

together with Modus Ponens as a rule if inference.
$\alpha \to \beta \text{,}\alpha \vdash \beta $.

Edit:

I’m fully aware that this can be easily proven with the Deduction theorem. In fact, it’s almost the very definition of the Deduction theorem. It can also be proven, for example, with a truth table: if both $\text{A}$ and $\text{B}$ are true then, obviously, $\left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B}$ is also true; if $\text{A}$ is true but $\text{B}$ is false then  $\text{A}\to \text{B}$ is false and $\left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B}$ is true, therefore, $\text{A}\vDash \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B}$, but that’s not the point.

I’m struggling to prove this using a Hilbert style proof:
$\text{A}\vdash \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B}$.
So far, I’ve tried several instances of A1 such as $\text{B}\to \left( \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B} \right)$, $\text{A}\to \left( \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{A} \right)$ etc. but none of them worked. I also tried instances of A2 like $\left( \text{A}\to \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right) \right)\to \left( \left( \text{A}\to \text{A} \right)\to \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right) \right)$.

I’d be really grateful if somebody could give me, let’s say, the first two elements in the proof sequence $\text{A},...,\left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B}$ after the premise $\text{A}$.
Thank you!

Comment: What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: What does $\vdash$ mean?

Comment: Do you know how to prove the Deduction Theorem for this Hilbert system?

Comment: Since you’ve written it as “$A \vdash (A \to B) \to B$”, the only real way to do it without the Deduction Theorem is to assume A, then prove the implicational version of the same theorem, namely $A \to ((A \to B) \to B)$. Then, having assumed A, you can derive $(A \to B) \to B$. To do this, you’ll need to prove $(\varphi \to \psi) \to (\varphi \to \psi)$ and $(\varphi \to (\psi \to \chi)) \to (\psi \to (\varphi \to \chi))$. Then, if you’ve already proven hypothetical syllogism, you are good to go.

Comment: Note that $A, A \to B \vdash B$ is trivial: just a one step Modus Ponens. Now apply the Deduction Theorem to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer your original question.

\begin{align*}
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!1. A \tag*{hypothesis}\\
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!2. A \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \tag*{(A1)}\\
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!3. (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A \tag*{1,2 MP}\\
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!4. (A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B) \tag*{theorem}\\
&\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!5. ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)) \rightarrow (((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B))\tag*{(A2)}\\
\end{align*}
Can you proceed from here?

Comment: 6. $\left( \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{A} \right)\to \left( \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B} \right)$ 4,5 MP

7. $\left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B}$ 3,6 MP
Therefore $\text{A}\vdash \left( \text{A}\to \text{B} \right)\to \text{B}$

Thank you very much! Your answer was just brilliant.
By the way, these Hilbert style proofs tend to be really tricky.